# Shiny app not displaying plotted points from single click method

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app I'm working on that allows you to upload a png then double click once to place a point, then double click again to place a 2nd point. A line will then be drawn between them. You can then make a single click along the line and it will place a different coloured point there.

I have the double click + line working, however when I single click it stores the correct coordinates in the reactive dataframe but then doesnt actually plot the point.

To reproduce this:

1. Upload any png
2. Double click to place a point
3. Double click somewhere else on the plot
4. Observe the line drawn between both points
5. Single click along the line. You will see the dataframe update but no points will be drawn.

Strongly suspect the bug is inside the `plotCoordinates` function, probably with

```
points_df <-
      reactive({
        data.frame(x = appState$points$x, y = appState$points$y)
      })
    if (nrow(points_df()) > 0) {
      basePlot <-
        basePlot + geom_point(data = points_df(),
                              aes(x, y),
                              color = "green",
                              size = 3)
    }
```

but I've been unable to locate the issue.

Fully Shiny code. I've cut out as much of the app as possible to just leave the minimum remaining to see how the double click works but single doesn't

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(png)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Otolith Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fileInput(
      "otolithImage",
      "Upload Otolith Image",
      accept = c("image/png", "image/jpeg")
    )),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(
        "otolithPlot",
        click = "plot_click",
        dblclick = "plot_dblclick",
        hover = "plot_hover"
      ),
      tableOutput("pointTable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Variables to store the state of the app
  appState <-
    reactiveValues(
      center = NULL,
      endPoint = NULL,
      points = data.frame(x = numeric(), y = numeric())
    )
  
  otolithImage <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$otolithImage, {
    otolithImage(readPNG(input$otolithImage$datapath))
  })
  
  plotCoordinates <- function() {
    inFile <- input$otolithImage
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    img <- otolithImage()
    basePlot <-
      ggplot() + annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(
        img,
        width = unit(1, "npc"),
        height = unit(1, "npc")
      ),
      -Inf,
      Inf,
      -Inf,
      Inf) +
      theme_void() +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, dim(img)[2]), ylim = c(0, dim(img)[1]))
    
    if (!is.null(appState$center)) {
      basePlot <-
        basePlot + geom_point(
          aes(x = appState$center[1], y = appState$center[2]),
          color = "blue",
          size = 3
        )
    }
    
    if (!is.null(appState$endPoint)) {
      basePlot <-
        basePlot + geom_point(
          aes(x = appState$endPoint[1], y = appState$endPoint[2]),
          color = "red",
          size = 3
        ) +
        geom_segment(
          aes(
            x = appState$center[1],
            y = appState$center[2],
            xend = appState$endPoint[1],
            yend = appState$endPoint[2]
          ),
          color = "black"
        )
    }
    
    points_df <-
      reactive({
        data.frame(x = appState$points$x, y = appState$points$y)
      })
    if (nrow(points_df()) > 0) {
      basePlot <-
        basePlot + geom_point(data = points_df(),
                              aes(x, y),
                              color = "green",
                              size = 3)
    }
    
    
    return(basePlot)
  }
  
  output$otolithPlot <- renderPlot({
    plotCoordinates()
  }, bg = "transparent")
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {
    if (is.null(appState$center)) {
      appState$center <- c(input$plot_dblclick$x, input$plot_dblclick$y)
    } else if (is.null(appState$endPoint)) {
      appState$endPoint <- c(input$plot_dblclick$x, input$plot_dblclick$y)
    }
    output$otolithPlot <- renderPlot({
      plotCoordinates()
    }, bg = "transparent")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    if (!is.null(appState$center) && !is.null(appState$endPoint)) {
      clickPoint <- c(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y)
      lineVector <- appState$endPoint - appState$center
      pointVector <- clickPoint - appState$center
      projectionFactor <-
        sum(lineVector * pointVector) / sum(lineVector * lineVector)
      
      if (projectionFactor >= 0 && projectionFactor <= 1) {
        newPoint <- appState$center + projectionFactor * lineVector
        appState$points <- rbind(appState$points, newPoint)
      }
    }
    output$otolithPlot <- renderPlot({
      plotCoordinates()
    }, bg = "transparent")
  })
  
  # Render the table with point coordinates
  output$pointTable <- renderTable({
    appState$points
  })
  
  # Hover line
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done 3 modifications but I'm not sur the three ones are necessary.

1. I put `appState` as an argument of the `plotCoordinates` function : `plotCoordinates <- function(appState)`. So you have to add it at each call.
2. I removed the `reactive` in the `plotCoordinates` function.
3. The most important. You have to set the names to `appState$points`:

```r
      if (projectionFactor >= 0 && projectionFactor <= 1) {
        newPoint <- appState$center + projectionFactor * lineVector
        appState$points <- rbind(appState$points, newPoint)
        names(appState$points) <- c("x", "y") ### <--- here
      }
```